# Why does transforming a 2-D shape defined by a 2xn matrix using a Singular Transformation Matrix always result in a line?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Say I have a geometric shape in $R^2$ whose vertices are defined as ordered pairs in a $2$x$n$ matrix, through which lines segments are drawn to "connect the dots" so to speak.

For examples a square with a height of 1, with a corner on the origin and the rest in Q1 would be

$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$

Why is it the case that any shape defined in such a way, when transformed by multiplication by a singular matrix $A$ results in a line? I know it has something to do with the fact that a $2$x$2$ defines via vectors a parallelogram whose area is equal to the determinate, and so a singular $2$x$2$ matrix defines one whose area is $0$.

But I can't find out why it would hold in a more general case such as the one I described.

Comment: What exactly do you want this transformation matrix to do? And why is it singular?

Comment: It's part of an assignment intended to help us better understand the nature of linear/matrix transformation on shapes in R2 (skews, rotations, projections etc), and one part deals with general things that can be said about transformations by singular and by invertable matrices. We saw that transformation by an invertible matrix will preserve things like parallelism and adjacent line-segments, and that transformation by a singular matrix collapses the shape to a line. We are asked why the latter is always the case. 1 hint was that the relationship between the Det. and the area is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $2 \times 2$ matrix can have a 0-, 1-, or 2-dimensional image.  If it has a 2-dimensional image, it is nonsingular (also called invertible).  If it has a 0- or 1-dimensional image, is is called singular (also, non-invertible).  An example of the former is $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, which clearly only has the vector $(0,0)$ for its image.  An example of the latter is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, which maps $(x,y)$ to $(x,0)$, i.e. to a 1-dimensional space.

Another way to think about this is that singular matrices take *some* non-zero vector to the zero vector, so they take all multiples of that vector to the zero vector.  This is a 1-dimensional subspace that is collapsed to a point.  A parallel collapsing happens everywhere else -- only a space perpendicular to that original vector survives.  (And in the 0-dimensional case, that perpendicular vector doesn't survive, because it is also sent to zero.)